# Why does my carbon-cache process occupies ever increasing amount of memory?

Tags: graphite, grafana

I'm using graphite+diamond to monitor hundreds of my servers. I found that the carbon-cache is killed by oom-killer every 20 hours. At first, I thought maybe it's due to my disk is relative slow since it's a SATA disk, not SSD. However, when I use iostat to check the util of my disk, it's only about 70%:

```
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
xvdap1            2.00     0.00  313.00    0.00  2484.00     0.00    15.87     0.84    2.67    2.67    0.00   2.43  76.05

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
xvdap1            1.50   144.50  261.50  306.50  2136.00  1804.00    13.87     1.13    2.00    3.03    1.11   1.27  72.30

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
xvdap1            0.50    97.00  137.00  332.50  1120.00  1718.00    12.09     1.98    4.23    6.69    3.21   1.70  79.90

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
xvdap1            2.50     0.00  163.50    0.00  1334.00     0.00    16.32     0.63    3.86    3.86    0.00   3.58  58.50

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
xvdap1            1.00   102.00  131.50  167.00  1048.00  1076.00    14.23     0.71    2.39    4.32    0.87   1.80  53.65

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
xvdap1            0.00     0.00   83.00    0.50   642.00     4.00    15.47     0.20    2.46    2.47    0.00   2.33  19.45
```

And my CPU usage is also not very high:

```
%Cpu0  : 34.8 us,  5.2 sy,  0.0 ni, 58.2 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  1.0 si,  0.7 st
%Cpu1  :  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,100.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu2  :  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 99.7 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.3 st
%Cpu3  :  6.5 us,  1.7 sy,  0.0 ni,  5.4 id, 85.7 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.7 st
```

How should I deal with this problem?

PS: our console.log is as follows:

```
07/06/2017 19:41:57 :: Sorted 16 cache queues in 0.000308 seconds
07/06/2017 19:41:57 :: Sorted 2 cache queues in 0.000200 seconds
07/06/2017 19:41:58 :: Sorted 564 cache queues in 0.000762 seconds
07/06/2017 19:41:58 :: Sorted 116 cache queues in 0.000388 seconds
07/06/2017 19:41:59 :: Sorted 820 cache queues in 0.001008 seconds
07/06/2017 19:42:00 :: Sorted 52 cache queues in 0.000354 seconds
07/06/2017 19:42:00 :: Sorted 1 cache queues in 0.000175 seconds
07/06/2017 19:42:01 :: Sorted 491 cache queues in 0.000530 seconds
07/06/2017 19:42:01 :: Sorted 101 cache queues in 0.000431 seconds
07/06/2017 19:42:01 :: Sorted 21 cache queues in 0.000283 seconds
07/06/2017 19:42:02 :: Sorted 1342 cache queues in 0.001589 seconds
07/06/2017 19:42:02 :: Sorted 224 cache queues in 0.000525 seconds
07/06/2017 19:42:02 :: Sorted 67 cache queues in 0.000299 seconds
07/06/2017 19:42:03 :: Sorted 1812 cache queues in 0.002230 seconds
07/06/2017 19:42:03 :: Sorted 360 cache queues in 0.000583 seconds
07/06/2017 19:42:03 :: Sorted 109 cache queues in 0.000430 seconds
07/06/2017 19:42:03 :: Sorted 27 cache queues in 0.000269 seconds
07/06/2017 19:42:04 :: Sorted 1570 cache queues in 0.001632 seconds
07/06/2017 19:42:05 :: Sorted 348 cache queues in 0.000656 seconds
```

Comment: Please provide sample of carbon's console.log. How many carbon-cache you are running? How many updates, creates it handles? How many metric reads (from graphite-web) you perform? What is the retention?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Now, my cluster configuration is this: a load-balancer is running at the top, which distributes updates to two carbon-relay instances running on two machines, there are 8 carbon-cache instances running on another 4 machines each of which is running two carbon-cache instances.

Comment: At present, I have two problems. The first is each carbon-cache machine's disk util is 100%, and the write iops is about 1000, and the write through put is about 5MB/s, which means each write is only about 4KB, why so small. The second is I configured 4 graphite-web instances running on those 4 carbon-cache machines seperately, and a nother graphite-web instance running on a single machine as the master, but I can't get the master graphite-web instance to query those 4 slaves even though I configured CLUSTER_SERVERS, why?

Comment: I've updated the question with a sample of our console.log

Comment: I've updated the question with a sample of our console.log. All of our metrics are collected every 15 seconds. By the way, the carbon-cache's machine's network inbound traffic is only about 500KB/s, why are they translated into 5MB/s when written to disk?

Answer (score 0):

Carbon has a ratelimit on how much writes it does per second. If your disk isn't saturated yet you can increase this. Be careful that if you set this too high you can starve other applications on this system or other hosts if you are on shared storage (SAN/NAS).

You can find this rate limit in the carbon.conf file. The setting is:

`MAX_UPDATES_PER_SECOND =`

To prevent the system from killing carbon you could consider configuring the maximum cache size. This will prevent carbon being killed, but will drop metrics if it hits the limit. The limit is in number of points in the cache, see the metric carbon.agents.$instance.cache.size to determine a good value. Also in carbon.conf:

`MAX_CACHE_SIZE =`

Also keep in mind that due to Python's Global Interpreter Lock (GIL), carbon can only run on one core at the same time. Your current CPU usage seems fine, but if your load increases more you could consider running 4 carbon caches (as you have 4 cores) with a carbon-relay in front to fully utilize your systems resources.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I already change MAX_UPDATES_PER_SECOND to inf, and MAX_CACHE_SIZE to 1GB, however, it still continue to occupy all of my 16GB memories and be killed by oom-killer. It seemed that these configuration didn't work. Why?

Comment: Meanwhile, the disk and cpu usage didn't have much change too

Comment: MAX_CACHE_SIZE is in cache size in datapoints, not in GB. Check the metrics in metrics->carbon->cache->size to determine the correct size. I don't understand why you disk utilization is not 100 % with these settings. Only suggestion I could give you is to to try running multiple caches, so there will be more parallel disk writes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Now, my cluster configuration is this: a load-balancer is running at the top, which distributes updates to two carbon-relay instances running on two machines, there are 8 carbon-cache instances running on another 4 machines each of which is running two carbon-cache instances.

Comment: At present, I have two problems. The first is each carbon-cache machine's disk util is 100%, and the write iops is about 1000, and the write through put is about 5MB/s, which means each write is only about 4KB, why so small. The second is I configured 4 graphite-web instances running on those 4 carbon-cache machines seperately, and a nother graphite-web instance running on a single machine as the master, but I can't get the master graphite-web instance to query those 4 slaves even though I configured CLUSTER_SERVERS, why?

Comment: Carbon tries do to write all datapoints for one metric in one write op. The ```MAX_UPDATES_PER_SECOND``` limits carbon to how many writes it can do per minute. If you set that to ```inf``` carbon will do as much writes as possible which results in small queues. If the queue is small, there are not much metrics available to write in one IOP thus the writes will be small. ```inf``` also results in 100% IO utilization. So lower the max_updates_per_second and your IOPS will go down and size per ioop goes up. The cluster question seems unrelated, better open a new question.